# How to separate two colliding circles?

Tags: c#, math, xna, collision-detection, geometry

I'm looking to separate two colliding circles, to push them back equally by the minimum amount so that they're perfectly separated.

I have this so far:

```
var totalRadius : Number = _circle1.radius + _circle2.radius;
var x : Number = _circle1.position.x - _circle2.position.x;
var y : Number = _circle1.position.y - _circle2.position.y;

var distanceSquared : Number = (x * x) + (y * y);

if (distanceSquared < totalRadius * totalRadius)
{   
    var distance : Number = Math.sqrt(distanceSquared);

    var separation : Number = totalRadius - distance;

    // No idea what to do now!

}
```

That much I've figured out so far.  So I know a collision has occurred and I know that each circle is `separation` amount into each other (so I guess divide by 2 to separate them equally).

The problem is that separation doesn't have any implied directionality and I don't know what to do.  I can't just do `circle1.position -= separation / 2; circle2.position += separation / 2` because that'll move both the X and Y axis equally.

How do I add directionality to `separation`?

Thanks!

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Direction.html

Comment: Okay that's helped but now I have another problem:  The objects aren't locking into position but the one with the higher velocity is pushing the other.  Should I edit this question or post a new one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Separating two colliding circles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266804/separating-two-colliding-circles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use unit vector to move both circles by `separation / 2`.

`unitVector = (circle1.Position - circle2.Position) / distance`

`circle1.Position += unitVector * seperation / 2`

`circle2.Position -= unitVector * seperation / 2`

Edit:

just change `seperation / 2` and/or `+-` part. It will allow you to move it by any distance you want.

Comment: Okay that's helped but now I have another problem: The objects aren't locking into position but the one with the higher velocity is pushing the other.  Should I edit this question or post a new one or do you think you could help?