# Separating two colliding circles

Tags: c#, math, xna, collision-detection

I'm trying to separate two circles that are colliding.  Thanks to the help of others, I'm right there!

This is my code:

```
var totalRadius : Number = _circle1.radius + _circle2.radius;
var x : Number = _circle1.position.x - _circle2.position.x;
var y : Number = _circle1.position.y - _circle2.position.y;

var distanceSquared : Number = (x * x) + (y * y);

if (distanceSquared < totalRadius * totalRadius)
{   
    var distance : Number = Math.sqrt(distanceSquared);

    var separation : Number = totalRadius - distance;

    var unitVectorX : Number = (_circle1.position.x - _circle2.position.x) / distance;
    var unitVectorY : Number = (_circle1.position.y - _circle2.position.y) / distance;

    _circle1.position.x += unitVectorX * (separation / 2);
    _circle1.position.y += unitVectorY * (separation / 2);

    _circle2.position.x -= unitVectorX * (separation / 2);
    _circle2.position.y -= unitVectorY * (separation / 2);
}
```

It works great if the circles have the same velocity.  The problem occurs when they have different velocities and the problem is because I'm splitting the separation evenly (`separation / 2)` I think!

Everything works perfectly if circle1 has a velocity of 1,0 and circle2 has a velocity of -1,0.  The two circles hit each other and stop.

If circle1 has a velocity of 2,0 and circle2 has a velocity of -1,0, the circles gradually move to the right.  I imagine this is what's happening:

frame1:

- circle1 (99, 100)
- circle2 (101, 100)

frame2:

- circle1 (101, 100)
- circle2 (100, 100)
- collision detected, corrected position of -0.5 and +0.5 respectively.
- circle1 (100.5, 100)
- circle2 (100.5, 100)

frame3:

- circle1 (102.5, 100)
- circle2 (99.5, 100)
- collision detected, corrected position of -1.5 and +1.5 respectively.
- circle1 (101, 100)
- circle2 (101, 100)

frame4:

- circle1 (103, 100)
- circle2 (100, 100)
- collision detected, corrected position of -1.5 and +1.5 respectively.
- circle1 (101.5, 100)
- circle2 (101.5, 100)

As you can see, both circles are gaining +0.5 to the right because of the difference of velocity.

So finally, my question:  How can I factor in their velocity into the equation so that it doesn't play a factor in their separation?

Thanks!

Comment: Once they've hit shouldn't you correct the velocities too, so they're not still moving towards each-other and colliding in the next frame?

Comment: I'm trying to create a mob of guys that don't stack on top of each other (overhead shooter) and so they'd just set their velocities to chase the player the next update again anyways.

Comment: To solve this problem you need to determine the 'point of impact'. See http://nonlinear.openspark.com/tutorials/vectors/index.htm section 'impact not intersection'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the point of impact, rather than just (arbitrarily) moving them both backwards equally.

A quick search found these links:

1. http://www.t3hprogrammer.com/research/circle-circle-collision-tutorial#TOC-Static-Circle-Circle-Collision-Dete (the section "Dynamic Circle-Circle Collision")
2. http://nonlinear.openspark.com/tutorials/vectors/index.htm (section "Impact, not intersection")

Answer (score 0):

to make the answer short: you will have to get [momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum#Conservation_of_momentum) in there ;)

As I guess you want to have the *masses* the same it comes down to "v1_before^2 + v2_before^2 = v1_after^2 + v2_after^2". As the wiki-article suggests I just "switch" the velocities.

What I do not understand is why you think the circles will both move to the right? Isn't this suppost to be a elastic collision? Then they should go in different directions if you want them to have same mass.

Comment: I don't want them to go in different directions.  Imagine like, a line forming.  As new guys come in from the left, they shouldn't push the guys to their right any further.  They should just hit the end of the line and stop.  But what's happening is that when the guy on the left comes in, he penetrates 2 units into the the guy on his right, pushing the guy on the left 1 unit left and the guy on the right 1 unit right (`separation` of 2 / 2 = 1) so I need to factor their velocities into it somehow.

Comment: If I get your right thats the situation with the "Newton's creaddle" - and this is just the formula: v1_before = 0, v2_before = 10, v1_after = 10, v2_after = 0 (switch) chained through all the guys. But in your example above both circles where moving in different directions, if both have the same mass it's not possible that both go the same direction after the *elastic* collision - you need some inelasticity then.

Comment: Ok, if he pushes *in* then this *is* some inelasticity - it will be harder to model this correctly. Do you really need this?